# Information regarding relocation to Trondheim, Norway

Tags: immigration, norway, skilled-migration

This question is regarding relocation to Trondheim for work reasons.

In this regard, I do have a couple of questions:

- What is the typical cost to rent a fully furnished flat?
- How much does food cost for a month?
- I’m moving there with my fiancée (she doesn’t have a job yet). I will be earning around 4000 Euros post tax, would that be sufficient?
- How difficult is for an expat to find a job? She is a reporting analyst for a mid-sized company and an Polish national.

Comment: You should break this down into separate questions. This allows answers to be useful as a reference for others.